# How can I set the focus of a TextBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, focus, double-click

I want to have focus in my `TextBox` after it is  double-clicked.

I simply try:

```
myTextBox.Focus()
```

The caret appears however it is not blinking, and no one can type in the text box.
What is the proper way to set the keyboard input focus on a `TextBox`?

Comment: Clicking it should be enough to make it focused... unless it's disabled of course

Comment: @Thomas, yes it gets focus, but the caret is not blinking and I can't input any text. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have `IsReadOnly` set by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but it was the first to come in a search and I don't see a valid answer, so posting one.

Problem is probably that your TextBox has Logical Focus, but not Keyboard Focus. Logical focus is set per scope, and WPF allows you to have multiple Focus Scopes in your application, so multiple controls can be logically focused, however only one control in your application can have Keyboard Focus.

```
myTextBox.Focus();          // Will set Logical Focus for myTextBox's Focus Scope
Keyboard.Focus(myTextBox);  // Will set Keyboard Focus to myTextBox
```

Comment: Thanks, your post lead me to find this article which explains in great depth the concepts you describe: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768(v=vs.110).aspx.